# mongodb copydb command copy gridfs db get 'BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) is invalid' error

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

i want copy a gridfs(db) from one machine to other machine.i'm use a `copydb` command.

```
> db.runCommand({copydb:1,fromhost:"192.168.1.90",fromdb:"fs_photos",todb:"fs_photos"})
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: BSONObj size: -791766910 (0x8298CED0) is invalid.
 Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: \u0014(\u0003: Object
Id('2800b83401d09a00301401da')",
    "code" : 10334,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

i'm checked a `fs_photos(fromdb,140G)` maximum length of file :

```
> db.fs.files.find({},{"length":1}).sort({"length":-1}).limit(5)
{ "_id" : "527156688f75550f14cdbe44", "length" : NumberLong(1369101) }
{ "_id" : "8197434919771504494", "length" : NumberLong(937048) }
{ "_id" : "7022162555617835884", "length" : NumberLong(893162) }
{ "_id" : "15191928400030169903", "length" : NumberLong(785255) }
{ "_id" : "18167776422270657585", "length" : NumberLong(777711) }
```

is my db error?

Comment: try to check the minimum size of file also.

Comment: The length of the file stored in GridFS isn't relevant; files are divided up into much smaller chunks for storage in a standard MongoDB collection. The error you are getting from the `copydb` command is related to the size of a *document* in your `fs_photos` database that appears invalid. I would suggest running [`validate(true)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/validate/) on each of the collections in your `fs_photos` database. It looks like there may be a corrupt document and you may need to [`repair`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.repairDatabase/).